# How to resolve the error when I install a APK file?

Tags: android, cocoscreator

Last building apk work is one month ago, and Today I build apk as I usually do. But the time error occurred.

I tried 
・move unnecessary files from resources folder, this action can prevent these files compiled into apk
・I packed other useful files into [cpk](https://amicitia.m.miraheze.org/wiki/CPK#CRI_Packed_File_Maker)

and sometimes the installation succeeded , and sometimes failed.

I tried 10 times
OK: 7times
NG: 3times

when I input

```sh
adb install GGGClient-release-signed.apk
```

the error message will return

> Performing Streamed Install
>   adb: failed to install .\GGGClient-release-signed.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed reading assets/res/raw-assets/e3/e37887ang in android.util.jar.StrictJarFile@b76a19a: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF has invalid digest for assets/res/raw-assets/e3/e37887ad-5de9-4a8a-ac6a-3c8b9904f5b2.pn37887ad-5de9-4a8a-ac6a-3c8b9904f5b2.png]

I tried another one apk (this apk has a cpk file in it)

and a similar error return

> adb: failed to install .\GGGClient-release.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION: Failed reading assets/assets.cpk in android.util.jar.StrictJarFile@82bf5f9: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF has invalid digest for assets/assets.cpk in assets/assets.cpk]

I want `OK:10 NG:0` result, but I don't know why this error occurs. Why the `[INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_UNEXPECTED_EXCEPTION]` occurs?